# Sort table by reputation and select rank + LIMIT to print above and below rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sort the table by the reputation and then select the position of the row [rank], it works fine, but I would like to print out 3 tables above and 3 tables below this rank row, but LIMIT rank,6 does not work :/ (Im sorry for that wrong formatted SQL :/) Would be thankful for every help :)

Here is what is working:

```
$query  = mysqli_query($con, "SET @rank=0");
$query  = mysqli_query($con, "
            SELECT 
               rank, 
               user_email, 
               reputation 
            FROM (
               SELECT 
                 @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, 
                 user_email, 
                 reputation 
               FROM accounts, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
               ORDER BY 
                 reputation DESC 
                 LIMIT 0,7
            ) t 
            WHERE 
               reputation >= '5' 
               OR reputation < '5'");
```

prints

```
[rank] [user_email]       [reputation]
1      mail1@gmail.com    20
2      test@test.com      15
3      mail2@gmail.com    10
4      othermail@gmail.com 5
5      hmmmmm@gmail.com    0
6      ouch@gmail.com      0
7      somemail@gmail.com  0
```

Comment: Er, what's the point of this? `reputation >= '5' OR reputation < '5'");` And what would your desired result look like?

Comment: That was an attempt to select below and above reputation 5 results ^^ Result should return rank 4 row with reputation and for example 2 results below and above this rank 4 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are finding the person with a reputation of 5, and want that person plus the 2 above and below that persons rank.

In which case maybe do the select as you essentially have to get the rank of the person with a reputation of 5, then join that back against the same select repeated to find those with a rank either side:-

```
SELECT Sub1.rank, Sub1.user_email, Sub1.reputation 
FROM 
(
    SELECT @rank2:=@rank2+1 AS rank, user_email, reputation 
    FROM accounts, (SELECT @rank2 := 0) r 
    ORDER BY reputation DESC 
    LIMIT 0,7
) Sub1 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT rank, user_email, reputation 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, user_email, reputation 
        FROM accounts, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
        ORDER BY reputation DESC 
        LIMIT 0,7
    ) t 
    WHERE reputation = '5'
) Sub2
ON Sub1.rank BETWEEN (Sub2.rank - 2) AND (Sub2.rank + 2)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but Im getting an error: Column 'rank' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Change it from rank to Sub1.rank in the main SELECT